# Как использовать ServiceLoader в Android?

Tags: java, android-sdk, android-studio, android

Никак не могу понять как использовать `ServiceLoder` в своем проекте. Где настроить конкретные реализации для интерфейсов? В документации сказано, что мол есть такая папка в проекте, называется она `META-INF/services/`. Мало того, что в проекте ее нет (просто даже на диске на всем нет ни одной `META-INF`), так и информацию о том, что в ней все-таки должно быть и в каком формате тоже не ясно, вроде как jar. 
Если с кодом все ясно и информации хватает, то вот с описанным выше аспектом... Быть может у кого есть успешный опыт работы с ServiceLoader в Android, поделитесь пожалуйста, ну или ссылочку киньте полезную, буду очень признателен.
Спасибо!

Comment: [Здесь](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-5things12/) вроде доступно написано.